# Why doesn't c replace *b?

Tags: c, scope, undefined-behavior, lifetime

I have this program:

```
    int* b;
    {
        int a = 5;
        b = &a;
    } //a gets destroyed here
    {
        int c = 7; //c replaces a?
        printf("c: %d\n", c);
    }
    printf("*b: %d", *b); //*b is still 5
```

why doesn't c replace *b or something like that? Is it because of some compiler optimazation (i'm using clang to compile, but i've tried with some online compilers and the result is still the same)

Comment: Why would `c` "replace" `a`? You are invoking undefined behavior by dereferencing a pointer to a variable that went out of scope.

Comment: because a is removed from the stack and c should go on top, replacing a.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The scopes of `a` and `c` don't overlap and they have the same type, so one might expect the compiler to assign the same address and/or register to them. But of course you're not really allowed to make assumptions like that and the code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's too much of assumptions. No one guarantees that it will be removed from stack. No one even guarantees it will be placed on stack.

Comment: `a` doesn't get "destroyed"; it goes out of scope, and (as @VladfromMoscow points out), so using a pointer to it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Compile this program and check the binary for how the compiler created your method stack frame

Comment: ok thanks everyone, I guess it's more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Basically you are asking this: "I am pointing my finger at a car on a parking lot. Someone steps into the car and drives away. I still point at the spot where it was parked. Another different car enters the parking lot. Why doesn't it park at the spot I'm pointing at?" Well, why would it? There's no law forcing the driver to park there. Or to park anywhere at all.

Comment: https://c.godbolt.org/z/EriGgM. In godbolt's C compiler a is placed with an offset of -16 and c with an offset of -12, (so it kinda ignored the blocks)

Comment: If you use the -O3 flag *b changes to 0 (that's why it's undefined behavior I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because the pointer p has an invalid value in the scope of this statement

```
printf("*b: %d", *b);
```

and there is an attempt to dereference it.

The pointer has an invalid (indeterminate) value because it does not point to an object. The object that was early pointed to by the pointer is not alive in this scope.

From the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 2. ... If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is
>      undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate
>      when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its
>      lifetime.